# ol3 - refresh individual layers?

Tags: openlayers-3

I'd like to implement a set-refresh-interval for various layers in ol3 but I cannot figure out a general-purpose solution.  I've found that calling source.changed() will refresh a ol.source.TileWMS source but it does not work with a ol.source.TileArcGISRest source.  Is there a general solution for this that doesn't involve refreshing the entire map?

Comment: Given that `ol.source.tile.Changed()` is still flagged as 'experimental', it's probably not working for `TileArcGISRest` at the moment.  It will probably act as you would expect when it becomes stable in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to do it "manually". This would be force redrawing.

```
var features = layer.getFeatures();
layer.clear();
layer.addFeatures(features);
```

If You are getting the data from the server - this is how refreshing after 1 sec would look like. (Projection should be changed to yours):

```
 var json = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
 window.setTimeout(function() {
  $.ajax(link, function(data) {
    var features = json.readFeatures(data
        {featureProjection:"EPSG:3857"});
    layer.clear();
    layer.addFeatures(features);
  });
}, 1000);
```

But I don't know if it helps with your problem. What is the reason for redrawing just one layer? Maybe more detailed explanation would help!

Comment: Think in terms of a WMS weather layer.  Your solution is nothing like what I was hoping for...a shared configuration option across layer types which causes the layer to be refreshed.